# How can I stop a task from being created?

Tags: tasks, opencti

I have written a softphone for SF Classic. It displays in an iframe on SF pages. When a call comes in, SF can be set to pop to the incoming caller's contact page, if one exists, or pop to the "new contact" page. Users generally want the screen pop to open a new tab so they don't lose whatever work they were doing when the call comes in. The call controller on the initial page stays open but kind of in a zombie state, no data is recorded from it. The call controller in the new tab is where notes can be taken, etc. When the call is terminated in that tab, both call controllers close and the call center goes back to its idle state.

In the Activity List View, linked to from the SF Home tab under the calendar (at least in my view), two Tasks get created. One has no contact info and Comments is set to "undefined". The other one has all the correct info.

I'm guessing a Task is created for both instances of the call center, although my code to create a task is only fired once, and that creates the Task I actually want.

Is there any way to make SF not save a task if, say, the Comments == undefined, or some other condition? Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: It's easy enough to toss a validation rule together to make the second task fail but you open up a whole can of worms. Something like that would usually stop all database operations in the same context which means neither task would be created. It seems to me the issue is somewhere in the softphone and that issue should be fixed instead of trying to work around it on the SF side.

Comment: But I wonder what triggers the creation of the incomplete task. My saveLog() code only gets called once, when the call is terminated from the active tab, and that creates the Task I want. Something else, something in SF as far as I can tell, must be creating the other one.